# How to make Flutter Markers in Firestone CRUD?

Tags: flutter, google-maps, crud

I am developing a function inside of a flutter app.

Its will work like this:

pressing a button adds a custom marker.

That is, a new page opens and you can complete: -Name -Description -Raiting -Google Map with current location, but allowing to move the marker to another side.

The problem is the following, I need to have a guide on how to implement it, since I have not found much information about it.

From what I understand, I should do a CRUD operations with FIRESTORE. I know how to store and modify the data of the TextFields of name - description - etc etc.

But I do not know how to implement the map view with marker not added automatically in the general map, when saving.

I will leave an example of how the marker is added to the screen.

It should be noted, that when the users enters, they will see a general map from Google Maps with their location and on one side of the screen there must be a button to add a marker.

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ACDM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can set a geopint to save that information if you want to do it with firebase.

Updating a value in firestore:

```
CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

    Future<void> updateUser() {
      return users
        .doc('ABC123')
        .update({'company': 'Stokes and Sons'})
        .then((value) => print("User Updated"))
        .catchError((error) => print("Failed to update user: $error"));
    }
```

doc: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage

You can also just save the information inside a var and pass it threw your screen. There you can access and set it.

```
onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home', arguments: YOURVAR);
        },
```

And on your detail screen:

```
 final ScreenArguments args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```

This gives you access to the value. More about it: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments